# Are .module files still required?

Tags: 8

I noticed that, in the current page crumb module, there is no .module file.

Why is that no longer necessary? As a test I added a .module file, but it seems it is not being read.  Where can I find documentation about using or not using a .module file in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.module` files are not required if you are not adding any procedural code. If you need to use any hooks, like `hook_theme` or `hook_form_alter`, yes, you need to do that in the `.module` file, because it cannot be done anywhere else. A lot of modules that extend base classes or provide services don't have any need to also include a `.module` file unless they provide something via `hook_help`, for example.

Some developers provide empty `.module` files, like:

```
<?php

// empty
```

I simply omit them if they have no code.

> And as a test I added a .module file but it seems it is not being read.

You'd have to elaborate on this, because any module that is enabled that has a `.module` file is definitely read. You may have to clear cache to pick up on changes.

Comment: yes but i added a module file to test it and it seems to be being bypassed completely.  Is there something in the services file that could be making that  .module file be bypassed ?  services:
  pup_taxonomy_breadcrumb.breadcrumb:
    class: Drupal\pup_taxonomy_breadcrumb\BreadcrumbBuilder
    arguments: ['@router.request_context', '@access_manager', '@router', '@path_processor_manager', '@config.factory',  '@title_resolver', '@current_user', '@path.current', '@menu.active_trail', '@plugin.manager.menu.link']
    tags:
      - { name: breadcrumb_builder, priority: 1 }

Comment: They are not related. You need to use some sort of debugging method to ensure the code in the `.module` file is even being hit to confirm that it is being loaded.

Comment: you are right I had spelled the name wrong.  thanks